# How to hide a WPF element to work correctly with an automation framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, automated-tests, ui-automation

The most common approach to hide a WPF control is setting `Visibility` attribute to `Hidden` or `Collapsed`. When I did this for sample application, and I was trying to find these elements by the automation framework, I got the items with `IsOffscreen` flag set to `true`.

For instance:

```
<Label Content="Hidden label" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

[image: Visibility: Hidden]

```
<Label Content="Collapsed label" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

[image: Visibility: Collapsed]

From my perspective, it looks reasonable but automation framework documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/uiauto-automation-element-propids
 says:

> Objects that the end-user does not perceive at all, or that are
>   "programmatically hidden" (for example, a dialogue box that has been
>   dismissed, but the underlying object is still cached by the
>   application) should not be in the automation element tree in the first
>   place (instead of setting the state of IsOffscreen to TRUE).

How can I achieve the result which is pointed out in the documentation?

Comment: I think that because it's still in the visual tree, it gets exposed to the automation framework. I guess you might have to have a Style or Control Template that just completely avoids adding the control to the tree rather than setting the visibility?

Comment: I do not know the answer to this but this is an amazing question. We have in the past also marked hidden controls as disabled to prevent people from interacting with them. This is not ideal though because with something like snoop the user could easily enable the control again.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue, Setting Visibilty to hidden/Collapsed does not remove the element from the visual tree, even though the control is not visible visually. And currently as per my knowledge there is no other property that can remove the element from the visual tree.

As a workaround, you can make use of **[ContentPresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter?view=net-5.0)** with triggers to include or exclude controls at runtime.

For example, in the below snippet I am deciding which label to include based on a condition. it is decided at runtime and only one is included in the visual tree.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
<ContentPresenter.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LabelContent1">
        <Label Content="Dummy" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LabelContent2">
        <Label Content="Dummy" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentPresenter.Resources>
<ContentPresenter.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LabelContent1}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={Binding Path=LabelText}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LabelContent2}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ContentPresenter.Style>
```

Reference:
https://tyrrrz.me/blog/conditional-content-presenting-via-wpf-contentpresenter